# Is it viable to short pitch different windings by different degrees of short pitching in the same synchronous generator?

Tags: design, generator, electric-machine, synchronous, harmonics

In the design of a synchronous generator one can chose to eliminate or reduce harmonics at the expense of emf.

The pitch factor \$K_p = \cos(\alpha/2)\$, which is always less than or equal to 1, describes how large the reduction of emf is at a given degree of short pitching.

Given that you have more than two windings in your design; is there any benefit in choosing different degrees of short pitching? I.e. a and a' is short pitched by an angle, \$\alpha_1\$. Whilst b and b' has a different degree of short pitching, \$\alpha_2\$. I am asking both in terms of Single- and Three-Phase generators, as well as in terms of different amount of poles.

In a two pole Three-Phase generator one could in theory have three different degrees of short pitching. Is there any benefit to this, as apposed to using the same degree of short pitching for every phase?

The picture below shows a winding that has been short pitched by 3 slots (33.75 degrees). The arrow on the outside of the stator represents the coil span of a full pitch winding, going all the way from the N to the S pole.

[image: Short pitch. vs full pitch]

Image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTsRSTzeqaM

Comment: I for one have never heard the term short pitching; could you define it?

Comment: A full pitch winding has a coil span all the way from the N to the S pole. A short pitched winding is moved a given amount of slots (which can be converted to degrees) closer to "itself". By closer to itself I am trying to convey that one part of the winding stays in its normal slot (imagine it being perpendicular to the N pole), whilst the other part is moved closer to that slot (moved away from the S pole, towards the N pole). Moving the winding 1 slot closer to itself in a 10 pole 1 phase generator results in a degree of short pitching which is equal to 36 degrees.

Comment: Each phase and each pole must be wound in the same way as the other phases and poles.

Comment: So there are no creative ways of combining different winding designs in the same generator. It would just cause the machine to function very badly? One should stick with the same number of turns, same copper wire diamter, same degree of short pitching, and so on, for the best performance?

Comment: Symmetry among the phases and poles is essential to a viable design. There are usually winding design alternatives within the limitations imposed by the need for symmetry. Larger machines have more possibilities for slots per pole per phase.